# Hibernate - Eager load just the proxies for manytomany

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, join

I have two tables joined by a join table:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "a" )
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column( name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false )
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany( targetEntity = B.class )
    @JoinTable( name = "a_b_join", joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "a_id" ), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "b_id" ) )
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();
}

@Entity
@Table( name = "b" )
public class B {
    @Id
    @Column( name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false )
    private long id;
}
```

There are a large number of A's in the database and relatively small number of B's.  Most A's will only have a single B, but could have several.  For any given result set of A's, there will only be a handful of distinct B's.  Eager loading the many-to-many would result in the same B's being fetched over and over again.  What I'm looking to do is have Hibernate fetch all of the ids for the B's for an A from the join table on the initial SELECT and populate the 'bs' Collection with proxies.  Then each B will only be fetched once in the session.

An alternative that would work for my application would be to somehow eager load a Collection of B ids from the join table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

An alternative would be to map the join table as an entity (let's call is `ABJoin`), replace the ManyToMany by a OneToMany targetting a `Set<ABJoin>`, and eager fetch this set. You would thus have a loaded Set of ABJoin, each having a non-initialized proxy to a B.

Comment: This is exactly what I decided to implement while I was waiting for a response.  I generally don't like creating entity classes for join tables, but this serves the purpose.